# Joint entropy for estimating conditional mutual sorting information

Tags: entropy

I'm going through [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51466637_Momentary_information_transfer_as_a_coupling_measure_of_time_series),
and their notation is confusing me a little bit.

In section III (Coupling Measures),
they consider two time series $x_t$ and $y_t$,
as well as their corresponding so-called permutation series $\pi_t^{\vartheta_x}$ and $\pi_t^{\vartheta_y}$;
if I understand correctly,
the latter are a synonym for an ordinal pattern sequence.

My first confusion is with respect to their mutual sorting information:

$$ I_{xy}^{\text{MSI}} (\tau) = H_x + H_y - H_{xy} $$

where, and I quote, "the joint entropy $H_{xy}$ is obtained from the joint probabilities $p_{ij}$ for $(\pi_t^{\vartheta_x}, \pi_{t+\tau}^{\vartheta_y}) = (\pi_{i \cdot}, \pi_{\cdot j})$".

1. The index $t + \tau$ means that the permutation series is "lagged"?
2. If yes, is this "common" for joint entropies? Seems kind of random.

Afterwards, they define the conditional version:

$$\begin{align}
I_{xy|z}^{\text{CMSI}} (\tau) &= H_{xz} + H_{yz} - H_{z} - H_{xyz} \\
z &= (\pi_{t}^{\vartheta_{z_x}}, \pi_{t+\tau}^{\vartheta_{z_y}}) \\
H_{xyz} &= p_{ijk} \; \text{for} \; [\pi_{t}^{\vartheta_x}, \pi_{t+\tau}^{\vartheta_y}, z]
\end{align}$$

3. Should I understand that all these joint entropies are calculated with the aforementioned lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake, here are my findings after a few days.

1. The ordinal pattern sequences are indeed shifted depending on the delay $\tau$;
   a positive one is like a lead and a negative like a lag.
2. I see now that these shifts are introduced because the authors were looking for delayed couplings,
   the joint entropy is probably the "usual" one.
3. This was the tricky thing.
   The joint entropies $H_{*z}$ are *not* calculated with a delayed $z$,
   but $H_{yz}$ *is* calculated with the delayed $\pi_{t + \tau}^{\vartheta_{z_y}}$.
   I suppose it makes sense in the context of the analysis,
   but it wasn't clear to me from the notation alone.